# DRY in django queries, reverse queries, and predicates

Tags: django, dry

I am frustrated that in Django I often end up having to write methods on a custom Manager:

```
class EntryManager(Manager):
    def filter_beatle(self, beatle):
        return self.filter(headline__contains=beatle)
```

... and repeat pretty much the same method in a different Manager for a reverse query:

```
class BlogManager(Manager):
    def filter_beatle(self, beatle):
        return self.filter(entry__headline__contains=beatle)
```

... and a predicate on Entry:

```
def headline_contains(self, beatle):
    return self.headline.find(beatle) != -1
```

[Note that the predicate on Entry will work on Entry objects that haven't even been saved yet.]

This feels like a violation of DRY. Is there some way to express this once and use it in all three places?

What I would like to be able to do is write something like:

```
q = Q(headline__contains="Lennon")
lennon_entries = Entry.objects.filter(q)
lennon_blogs = Blog.objects.filter(q.reverse(Entry))
is_lennon = entry.would_filter(q)
```

... where 'headline__contains="Lennon"' expresses exactly once what it means to be 'an Entry about "Lennon"', and this can be used to construct reverse queries and a predicate.

Comment: Do you mean `Entry.objects.filter(…)` ? Also you haven't explained what you're trying to do.

Comment: Altered the filter to operate on the Manager rather than trying to construct an invalid object. The 'predicate' is still wrong, I'll leave that to the OP to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The best place for this is a custom manager. According to django's guidelines a manager class is the best place for code that is affecting more than one object of a class.

```
class EntryManager(models.Manager):
    def filter_lennons(self):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(headline__contains='Lennon')

class Entry(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = EntryManager()

lennons = Entry.objects.filter_lennons()
```

Comment: My question was about needing to re-state a condition several times, and uses a custom manager. I'm not sure what this answer is intending to add.

Answer (score 0):

You should <strike>never</strike> rarely have to do the following:

```
if entry.headline.find('Lennon') >= 0:
```

because the filter should take care of restricting the result set to the instances you're interested in.

If you're going to be using the same filter multiple times, you can create a [custom manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) or a simple class method.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    # this really should be on a custom manager, but this was quicker to demonstrate
    @classmethod
    def find_headlines(cls, text):
        return cls.objects.filter(headline__contains=text)

entries = Entry.find_headlines('Lennon')
```

But really, the DRYness has already been contained within the Queryset API. How often are you really going to be hard coding the string 'Lennon' into a query? Usually, the search parameter will be passed into a view from a GET or POST. Perfectly DRY.

So, what is the actual problem? Other than exploring the queryset API, have you ever had to hard code lookup values in multiple queries like your question?

Comment: Thanks for the edits and clarifying questions. It isn't about hard-coding 'Lennon', it's about having to express 'Lennon-ness' [or really 'some-beatle-ness'] three different ways.

The need for a predicate might be, for example, if I have a query that matches a bunch of entries, but I want to display all the Lennon entries in red.

Answer (score 0):

For the "reverse filter" case you can use a subquery:

```
Blog.objects.filter(entries__in=Entry.objects.filter_beatle("Lennon"))
```

Reusing or generating predicates is not possible (in general) as there are predicates that cannot be expressed as queries and queries that cannot be expressed as predicates without db access.

Comment: The subquery solves the DRY issue at the cost of another round trip to the database. I do this for cases where I expect that burden to light.
But if there are a lot of Lennon entries, I'd rather have the database do the join than create an intermediate result in Python.

Comment: The database will do the join. Have a look at [the docs for `in` lookups](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in).

Comment: Have enough IDs in that IN clause, and you can hit the db limit for max packet size (in MySQL, at least). I would never use an arbitrary number of elements in an IN clause. It won't scale. And when it fails, it fails silently, just truncating your IDs.

Answer (score 0):

My most common use for the predicate seems to be in asserts. Often something like:

```
class Thing(Model):
    class QuerySet(query.QuerySet):
        def need_to_be_whacked():
            # ... code ...

    def needs_to_be_whacked(self):
        return Thing.objects.need_to_be_whacked().filter(id=self.id).exists()

    def whack(self):
        assert self.needs_to_be_whacked()

for thing in Thing.objects.need_to_be_whacked():
    thing.whack()
```

I want to make sure that no other code is calling whack() in state where it doesn't need to be whacked. It costs a database hit, but it works.